# asp.net c# invalid token "for" in class, to generate random code

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to create a method to generate a random code. The method will be used when the page loads to assign a default random code to a textbox. The user will also have the option of clicking a generate button to assign a new code if they don't like the one they see.

I right clicked the solution, clicked add new item, found c# class and clicked that, gave a name RandomCode. The nodes were added in the solution explorer  RandomCode.cs and RandomCode.

The code works in the code behind on the button but when I copy it to this new class to create a method the "for" word is highlighted in red and the message shows "invalid token for in class". The code is listed below. How do I create the method to generate the random number.

asp.net 4.6

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace xmlInsertUpdateDelete
{
    public class RandomCode
    {

                //string alphabets = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
                //string small_alphabets = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
                //string numbers = "1234567890";

        //string characters = numbers;
        string characters = "1234567890";
        //if (rbType.SelectedItem.Value == "1")
        //{
        //characters += alphabets + small_alphabets + numbers;
        //characters += numbers;
        //}
        //int length = int.Parse(ddlLength.SelectedItem.Value);
        int length = 5;
        string otp = string.Empty;
                for (int i = 0; i<length; i++)
                {
                    string character = string.Empty;
                    do
                    {
                        //int index = new Random().Next(0, characters.Length);
                        int index = new Random().Next(0, 5);
        character = characters.ToCharArray()[index].ToString();
    } while (otp.IndexOf(character) != -1);
                    otp += character;
                }
//lblOTP.Text = otp;
txtRandomCode.Text = otp;

    }
}
```

Comment: the code must be in a method within the class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There should be an method cover your code.
Example I Create a method Random

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;



    public class RandomCode
    {

        //string alphabets = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
        //string small_alphabets = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
        //string numbers = "1234567890";

        //string characters = numbers;
        string characters = "1234567890";
        //if (rbType.SelectedItem.Value == "1")
        //{
        //characters += alphabets + small_alphabets + numbers;
        //characters += numbers;
        //}
        //int length = int.Parse(ddlLength.SelectedItem.Value);
        public string Random()
        {
            int length = 5;
            string otp = string.Empty;
            for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
            {
                string character = string.Empty;
                do
                {
                    //int index = new Random().Next(0, characters.Length);
                    int index = new Random().Next(0, 5);
                    character = characters.ToCharArray()[index].ToString();
                } while (otp.IndexOf(character) != -1);

                otp += character;
            }
            //Option to assign here txtRandomCode.Text or out side
            //txtRandomCode.Text = otp; 
            return otp;
        }


    }
    //outside
    /*
     var r = new RandomCode ();
     txtRandomCode.Text = r.Random()
     */
```

Comment: Thanks, when I uncomment those lines //txtRandomCode.Text = otp; //return otp; the message displays "the name txtRandomCode does not exist in the current context. The warning window shows potential fixes for generating some classes and things.

Comment: Oh, sorry the txtRandomCode.Text = otp; is unable to used in the body of method Random, C# will not know it. so you should use the outside suggestion, create instance for class and call the method : var r = new RandomCode ();
     txtRandomCode.Text = r.Random()

Comment: Should I right click the solution and add new item, and click the c# class in a new file or use an existing file?

Comment: Yes, it's better to create a new class as you talked.It's good practice to make a file for a class.

Comment: Thanks, I guess one class is to request the generator and one is to generate the code. It sounds like one should be RandomCodeRequest and the other RandomCodeGenerate. So, then I call the method RandomCodeRequest in the page load.